# Why no Yerushalmi on the end of Shabbat?

Tags: talmud-yerushalmi

Any ideas why the last 4 chapters of Shabbat have no Yerushalmi?

Only the Mishnayot are printed, with no *Gemara*.

By comparison, the last 4 chapters of Shabbat in the Bavli stretch over 15 Daf.

Are we missing these pages, or is there another reason?

Comment: Similar reason to why end of Nidah is missing, No?

Comment: בארבעה פרקים מזה. בארבעה העתקות ישנות לא ראינו במחזה. כאשר שמענו עוד נחזה  רצנו כשי החידוש הזה.

Comment: @Shmuel Can you please honor the reader's with some elucidation on both of your comments?

Comment: @Shmuel - amazing! My Yerushalmi doesn't have that; just has the last 4 Prakim printed in Yerushalmi "halacha" style". That should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @Shmuel - and why is end of Niddah missing?  Sounds intersting.

Comment: @Danny Shoemann same reason why Kodashim is missing? (And last perek of makos)

Answer (score 4):

It seems over the years the Yerushalmi wasn’t learned too much. So some stuff got lost, and when it came time to print they literally just didn’t have the material. (That’s my own take on it)

Most of Niddah

Last perek of Makkos

Seder kodashim

*Last 4 perakim of Shabbos*

My Yerushalmi printed in Berlin, 1929 has some messages, like:
At the end of Shabbos:

> בארבעה פרקים מזה. בארבעה העתקות ישנות לא ראינו במחזה. כאשר שמענו עוד נחזה רצנו כשי החידוש הזה

At the end of makos:

> לא מצינו גמרא ירושלמית בפרק זה

I have heard that Rishonim (like Tosafos, for instance) quote Yerushalmis in Kodashim that have since been lost.

(Not to be confused with the forged [Yerushalmi Kodashim](http://www.yerushalmionline.org/articles/yerushalmi_on_kodshim.pdf) available [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/49587) and [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/49586))

At the end of [my] shas the followed image appears: 
Basically saying that they didn’t have it at the print house and some other stuff. 
[image]

For plenty of info on Yerushalmi see http://www.yerushalmionline.org and https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerusalem_Talmud

Also, every once in a while they find some ancient fragments to add a couple lines. And Yerushalmi texts are often messed up.

Comment: It's not so clear there ever was a Yerushalmi on Kodshim to be lost